# how to sort by value of a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

sort list of a dictionary by value
I have been trying to use lambda but I could not figure it out.

```
scale = {'A+': 4.3, 'A': 4.0, 'A-': 3.7,
   'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 'B-': 2.7,
   'C+': 2.3, 'C': 2.0, 'C-': 1.7,
   'D+': 1.3, 'D': 1.0, 'D-': 0.7,
   'F' : 0.0}

subject = {'math':  {('Tom', 'B'), ('Kevin','D')},
   'History':  {('Kate', 'A+'),('Eric','C'),('Hannah','F')}, 
   'English':  {('Eli', 'B-')}}`
from collections import defaultdict
mingrade = 1.7
def pass(subject, mingrade):
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for subject_name,subject_grade in subject.items():
        for student,grade in subject_grade:
        if scale[grade]>=mingrade:
            output[subject_name]+=[student]
return output
```

I got output like 
{'math': ['Tom'], 'History':  {('Kate'),('Eric')},'English':  {('Eli')}
but I want to sort by name and grade for example
'History':  {('Kate'),('Eric') will become 'History':  {('Eric'),('Kate')} alphabetically order.
another one I want to get it by grade. student who got higher grade comes first.

Comment: First a couple things your indentation is incorrect on your function with both the return line and the `if` statement inside your second `for` loop. Second you shouldn't create a function/variable using a protected word in python. `pass` is a Python keyword https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-pass_stmt

Comment: I'm confused on how you wanted them sorted you say you want the student with the highest grade to be listed first but you also want them in alphabetical order those are conflicting sort parameters

Comment: I want 2 different code one with the highest grade to be listed first and another one in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in order to get two different outputs with two different sorts I took your code and then created two outputs for your function with one sorted alphabetically and one sorted by grade.

```
scale = {'A+': 4.3, 'A': 4.0, 'A-': 3.7,
   'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 'B-': 2.7,
   'C+': 2.3, 'C': 2.0, 'C-': 1.7,
   'D+': 1.3, 'D': 1.0, 'D-': 0.7,
   'F' : 0.0}

subject = {'math':  {('Tom', 'B'), ('Kevin','D')},
   'History':  {('Kate', 'A+'),('Eric','C'),('Hannah','F')}, 
   'English':  {('Eli', 'B-')}}
from collections import defaultdict
mingrade = 1.7
def test(subject, mingrade):
    alpha_sort = defaultdict(list)
    grade_sort = defaultdict(list)
    for subject_name,subject_grade in subject.items():
        #here i sort the sets first alphabetically and then by grade
        #the sorted function allows me to pass a function on which i want
        #to sort them as with the key keyword
        sort_alpha = sorted(subject_grade, key=lambda x: x[0].lower())
        sort_grade = sorted(subject_grade, key=lambda x: scale[x[1]], reverse=True)
        #now I loop over each sorted list as you did and store them in a 
        #seperate default dicts
        for student,grade in sort_grade:
            if scale[grade]>=mingrade:
                grade_sort[subject_name]+=[student]
        for student,grade in sort_alpha:
            if scale[grade]>=mingrade:
                alpha_sort[subject_name]+=[student]

    return alpha_sort, grade_sort
alpha, grade = test(subject, mingrade)
print(alpha, grade)
```

which gives this output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'math': ['Tom'], 'History': ['Eric', 'Kate'], 
'English': ['Eli']}) 
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'math': ['Tom'], 'History': ['Kate', 'Eric'], 
'English': ['Eli']})
```

Comment: I am getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Did you use the code i gave you exactly because i just ran it again cutting and pasting from here and it ran fine for me. Are you working in python 3? also can you give me the full error trace so i can see what line is giving it issues.